# iPhone Memory Management (UIBarButtonItem)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

In my .h file I declare a `UIBarButtonItem` called `saveButton`, that will be displayed in the User Interface. The button itself is created in `viewDidLoad` (not via Interface Builder). Do I now have to set it to `nil` in `viewDidUnload`? Which of Apple's documents explains stuff like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set my objects to nil in `viewDidUnload` and release them in `dealloc`. Due to memory warnings your view can get unloaded and then loaded again when you need it which is why I initialise my properties in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

You should release it and optionally set it to nil in your dealloc method.  Apples documentation on this is available here:  [Memory Management Programming Guise](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)